# consumo de webservice funciona correctamente en Tomcat pero falla en WebLogic 12c

Tags: java, jpa, tomcat, servlets, weblogic

He logrado consumir un servicio usando  `jax-ws`, cuando he desplegado en tomcat todo ha funcionado correctamente, pero cuando he desplegado en weblogic todo funciona bien hasta que intento consumir el servicio y arroja el siguiente error:

> `could not commit jpa transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.rollbackexception`

¿Se necesita alguna configuracion adicional para desplegar en weblogic?

He creado este archivo `weblogic.xml` dentro de la carpeta `WEB-INF` pero aun asi el servicio sigue sin responder en el servidor weblogic. Este es mi codigo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<jsp-descriptor>
<keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
<debug>true</debug>

</jsp-descriptor>
<container-descriptor>
<prefer-application-packages>
  <package-name>org.slf4j</package-name>
  <package-name>c3p0</package-name>
  <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
  <package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</package-name>
  <package-name>org.apache.*</package-name>
  <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>

<show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
</container-descriptor>
<context-root>/sibad</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

¿Alguna idea de como sulucionarlo?

Comment: tal vez deberías de poner más de la traza para ver si hay algún inicio